# A quick doubt on a Calculus problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am almost sure the following problem, which is in an exercises list I've gotten assigned from college, is somehow mistated, but anyway, here's the statement:

> Based on data compiled by the Group Health Association of America, the
>   number of people receiving their care in an HMO (Health Maintenance
>   Organization) from the beginning of 1984 through 1994 is approximated
>   by the function $f(t)=0,0514t^3-0,85t^2+6,8147t+15,6524$, where $f(t)$
>   gives the number of people in millions and $t$ is measured in years,
>   with $t = 0$ corresponding the beginning of 1984.
>
> a) At what time, in a given time interval, was the number of people
>   receiving medical care in HMO growing most rapidly?

The way I went about it was by calculating $f'$, which gives the rate of rage of the number of people etc., and then trying to find its global maximum, which would give the desired value of $t$, right? However, $f'$ is a parabola, so it never attains a global maximum. So, am I missing something out here or is the problem indeed mistated? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Hint: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: The quadratic function that you get for $f'$ doesn't attain a global maximum on $\mathbb{R}$, but it does attain an absolute maximum on the interval under consideration in this problem.

Comment: Oh, of course! What a silly question of mine. Thank you

Comment: It's nit-picking, but "$f'$ is a parabola, so it never attains a global maximum" is true iff the parabola opens up. (That's certainly the case in your example, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

To find the maximum of a function over an interval, you check the points where its derivative is zero and the endpoints of the interval.  In your case the maximum comes at $t=0$.

Comment: Well, since the interval under consideration is $[0,10]$, shouldn't the maxium come at $t=0$? Since $f'(0)=6.81>f'(10)=5.24$

Comment: Yes, that is right.  I had dropped the $2$ multiplier in the middle term.